# Object Hierarchy in OOP

Tags: class, oop, object

What is Object Hierarchy actually,I cant differentiate it with Class Hierarchy.Are they actually the same thing?I have looked into answers on stackoverflow and googled it,but haven't found any clear explanations yet :(

Comment: @JeroenVannevel ... what? In what context? An object is not a class. An object is an instance of a class.

Comment: @dcastro: yes, there is that distinction ofcourse but I was referring to the situation as asked: there is no difference between speaking about a class hierarchy and an object hierarchy (I suppose my initial comment was a little too minimalistic).

Answer (score 3):

There are not the same thing, they are in fact **very different things**. Confusingly enough, class hierarchy is informally often called object hierarchy.

In order to understand the difference, you should understand the difference between **class and object**. This is the heart of OO theory and you can read about it in any OO book or simply google it.

As a quick help, here is a simple example of both hierarchies and both (class and object):

A class hierarchy refers to a taxonomy of **classes** based on inheritance relationships between them - in the following example all classes under the Vehicle (excluding Engine and Wheel), directly or indirectly inherited from it are forming a **class hierarchy**:
[image]

**Objects** are instances of classes, so they "live" on another level of abstraction (e.g. in run-time). Classes are templates for creating their concrete instances - objects. Objects connect themselves and this network of interconnected object form **object hierarchy**. Here, the objects Car, Engine and 4 Wheels are inteconnected in a object hierarchy:
[image]

Comment: I think you're mixing up the terms a bit too. You're referring to the difference between composition and inheritance. I'm not sure of the terms myself, but I'm pretty sure it's not called "class hierarchy" vs "object hierarchy".

Comment: No, I'm talking about the difference between the "world of classes" and "world of objects", that's the fundamental thing behind those hierarchies. Both "Hierarchies" are kind of informal terms, but in the world of classes, the hierarchies are formed by inheritances, while in the world of objects by the interconnected instances.

Comment: SO finally,it means that classes obtain hierarchy through inheritance and on object level,it is an issue with composition,r8?

Comment: With the "Instances of composition" actuially. :)

Comment: And once more, don't pay much attention on the term "hierarchy", but rather on understanding the fundamental difference between class and object, and in consequence, the process od "building" the run-time object-link structure, based on a class structure.

Comment: You can represent objects hierarchically in Javascript. And Javascript is an OO language with no Classes.

Comment: That's right, but that does not change anything. If we have so called "OO language with no classes", why we should not have OO hierarchy without classes? :) Most of the so called OO languages are not fully OO, so it does not make sense to look for a formalism in this sense.